# Java error codes

Tags: java, netbeans, command-prompt

```
Unrecognized option: -cp.HelloWorldApp
Error: Could Not Create The Java Virtual Machine
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. The program will exit 


//Seperate codes or responses.


Error: Registry Key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\Current Version'
has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment
```

I am trying to learn Java with Netbeans 8 IDE. I get the second response after inserting the `java -cp.HelloWorldApp` command in the command prompt. The first I get after reading that JDKs below 8 have 3 exe files `java`,`javaw`,`javaws` and should delete them, so I did. I have JDK 7 and 8 installed and I don't know which one I used for the code for the HelloWorldApp. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your SDK version to 1.7 from 1.8

In netbeans, go to Tools -> Java Platform . There, click on Add Platform, point it to  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25. You can either set the another JDK version or remove existing versions.

Comment: I uninstalled all JDKs and started from scratch ,  yet the conflict persists ?? Although I currently have JDK 8 on my PC and not 1.7 ?

Comment: You certainly have a 1.7 somewhere. The error message says so.

Comment: From the error, I understand that JDK 1.7 is required therefore you should change your JDK version on netbeans. You don't need to uninstall JDK 1.8, only need to change settings to 1.7 :) If problem will not solved with 1.7 then we could try other way...